# beautifulsoup web crawling search id list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, ncbi

I am attempting to crawl the [ncbi eutils webpage](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=%22D-PANTOTHENIC%20ACID%22&retmax=2000&usehistory=y&field=Title/Abstracts). I want to crawl the Id list from the web as shown in the below:

[image]

Here's the code for it:

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

  def get_html(url):  
      """get the content of the url"""  
      response = requests.get(url)
      response.encoding = 'utf-8'  
      return response.text  


  def get_pmid(html):   
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
      for texts in soup.select('body'):
          text = texts.get_text()
          print text

  url_ncbi = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=%22D-PANTOTHENIC+ACID%22&retmax=2000&usehistory=y&field=Title/Abstracts"  
  html = get_html(url_ncbi)
  get_pmid(html)
```

I want to use the select function to acquire the text but cannot find the right code for the script: for texts in `soup.select('    ')`.

I'm confused by the multiple layers of classes and ids from the web code like this:

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting all `ID` tags you can use `find_all()` function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  


def get_html(url):  
  """get the content of the url"""  
  response = requests.get(url)
  response.encoding = 'utf-8'  
  return response.text  


def get_pmid(html):   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') 
    rv = []
    for id_tag in soup.find_all('id'):
        rv.append(id_tag.text)
    return rv

url_ncbi = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=%22D-PANTOTHENIC+ACID%22&retmax=2000&usehistory=y&field=Title/Abstracts"  
html = get_html(url_ncbi)
all_ids = get_pmid(html)
print(all_ids)
```

Prints:

```
['29737393', '29209902', '24632028', '23727638', '22536244', '22052867', '15371742', '12204559', '10885798', '16348362', '3096335', '3734807', '6247641', '6997858', '761345', '108510', '355840', '1003285', '4676550', '5804470', '6076800', '6076775', '6012920', '14091285']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! So we find the content text is 'id' in your script, may I understand?

Comment: @Thomas.Q soup.find_all('id') finds all tags <id> and then the .text() method returns all text inside this tag.

Comment: Sure. I got it. Thx!